# Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" // undefined

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I am trying to push data from a `v-text-field` onto a json file. When i tried it on Postman it worked so I'm guessing the error is coming from the client side

product.vue

```html
<v-container>
   <v-row>
      <v-col>
         <v-text-field
            label="440"
            v-model="onetext"
            ></v-text-field>
         <v-text-field
            label="Card Type"
            v-model="twotext"
            ></v-text-field>
         <v-text-field
            label="Card Type"
            v-model="threetext"
            ></v-text-field>
         <v-text-field
            label="Card Type"
            v-model="fourtext"
            ></v-text-field>
         <v-text-field
            label="Card Type"
            v-model="fivetext"
            ></v-text-field>
         <v-text-field
            label="Card Type"
            v-model="sixtext"
            ></v-text-field>
         <v-text-field
            label="Card Type"
            v-model="seventext"
            ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
   </v-row>
</v-container>
</v-card-text>
<v-card-actions>
   <v-spacer></v-spacer>
   <v-btn color="primary"  @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
   <v-btn color="primary"  @click="create">Save</v-btn>
</v-card-actions>
```

```js
import ProductService from '@/services/ProductService'
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      product: null,
      onetext: null,
      twotext: null,
      threetext: null,
      fourtext: null,
      fivetext: null,
      sixtext: null,
      seventext: null
    }
  },
  async mounted() {},
  methods: {
    async create() {
      try {
        await ProductService.create(this.onetext, this.twotext, this.threetext, this.fourtext, this.fivetext, this.sixtext, this.seventext)
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.response.data.message
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ProductService.js

```
export default {
    create(){
        return Api().post('/product', one, two, three, four, five, six, seven);
    }
}
```

ProductRouter:

```
router.post("/", function(req, res){
    try{
        const fileName = path.resolve("server",'../product.json');
        const file = require(fileName);

        const product = {
            101: req.params.one,
            201: req.params.two,
            420: req.params.three,
            440: req.params.four,
            444: req.params.five,
            451: req.params.six,
            452: req.params.seven
        }

        fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(product, null, 2), function(err){
            if (err){
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("the file was saved");
            res.status(200).json(product);
        });
    } catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({
            message: "Error writing to file",
            error: err
        });
    }
})
```

> ERR: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

- Why am i getting this error and is there anything i could do to fix this?

EDIT: Expected product.json file

```
{
  "101": 1.9,
  "201": 2.18,
  "420": 4.1,
  "440": 9.2,
  "444": 11.16,
  "451": 122.12,
  "452": 11.9
}
```

Comment: May you are not getting data here `catch(error){
            this.error = error.response.data.message
          }` try and check with `console.log(error.response)`

Comment: hi that got rid of the error. however it just prints now in the console "undefined" - whenever i click on the button to create a product and no product is created in the json file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

Your `create` function is using arguments that were not passed.  Change it to:

```js
export default {
    create(one, two, three, four, five, six, seven){ // <-- add arguments
        return Api().post('/product', one, two, three, four, five, six, seven);
    }
}
```

---

**Improvement:**

Simplify everything:

1) Move all form model data into one data object `formData`:

```js
return {
  // ...
  formData: {
    onetext: null,
    twotext: null,
    ...
  }
}
```

2) In the template, instead of hard-coding the list of `v-text-field`, use `v-for` to loop over that `formData` object:

```html
<v-text-field v-for="(value, key) in formData" :key="key"
              label="Card Type" v-model="formData[key]"
></v-text-field>
```

3) Pass the `formData` object in the `create` method instead of multiple arguments:

```js
await ProductService.create(this.formData);
```

4) Change `ProductService.create`, `Api().post`, and `router.post` to use/pass that object:

```js
create(formData){ // <-- Accepts an object now
    return Api().post('/product', formData); // <-- Passes the object
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/qu6myf5j/)

Comment: hey thank you for your answer. that seemed to have solved my problem. however the issue now is, when i check my product.json file. it's contents is "{}" . Is there a specific reason for this? in theory, what i expected is once the POST request is called. It should create a new product in the json file with the data from the textfields

Comment: ps. i will add my product.json file to the question

Comment: In `router.post`, have you tested both `file` and `req.params` successfully in the console? I'm guessing you haven't passed all 7 of those params.  Your route path would have to look something like this:  `:one/:two/:three/:four/:five/:six/:seven`.  I think you want `req.body` instead.

Comment: hey Dan, played around with it some more and your right. `req.body` is what i wanted to use. So it writes to the json file the way i want it to. only problem now is it only writes the first parameter. so onetext instead of all of them. any reason why this may be the case?

Comment: switched to your improvements and updated `Api.post()` with `formData`. my only question is what changes would i need to make in my router?

Comment: Let's move this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212075/61315257)