# Add new properties to an object used in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I want to add data (from two `v-text-fields`) in my product component to my data that I pass to the server.  So that if the user adds the values '444' and '230' to the `v-text-fields`, the entry would be:

```
{
    "444": 230
}
```

So far, I have hard coded the '444' and managed to get the value '230' passed. But how do i pass both '444' and '230' according to user inputs from a `v-text-field`?

product.vue

```html
<v-content>
  <v-container>
    <code>formData:</code> {{ formData }}<br />
    <v-btn color="primary"  @click="create">Save</v-btn>
    (Check console)<br />
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-text-field v-for="(value, key) in formData" :key="key"
          label="Card Type" v-model="formData[key]"
          ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    dialog: false,
    product: null,
    error: null,
    formData: {
      444: null,
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  async create() {
    try {
      await ProductService.create(this.formData);
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error.response.data.message
    }
  }
}
```

What changes would i need to make in my component so that formData is based on user input from another `v-text-field`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61315257/2185093).  To add a new item to that basic `formData` hash, you would do something like this:

```html
<div>
   <v-text-field label="Product #" v-model="newKey"></v-text-field>
   <v-text-field label="Card Type" v-model="newValue"></v-text-field>
   <v-btn @click="$set(formData, newKey, newValue)">+</v-btn>
</div>
```

This uses `$set` to add new properties to `formData`.